# All C# Syntax in a single cs file

Tags: c#

I heard about there being a cs file on the internet from a couple different sources that has all of the syntax in C# in a single file, which would be really good for a crash course to get ready for a job I have. Unfortunately no one could point me to the exact file, has anyone heard or seen anything like this?

Comment: I'm not sure I would want to see this file ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this the one you're looking for?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2010/05/11/updated-c-all-in-one-file.aspx

Comment: I never saw the original one specifically, but this fits the bill exactly. Thank you so much! Time to get studying! :)

Comment: You're welcome!  And regarding brushing up on C# - depending on your current level of familiarity with the language, I'm not sure if this file will be very helpful.  I was going to suggest O'Reilly's Learning C# which I've found to be great for brushing up and I've lent it to others and they had the same reaction.  Here it is on Amazon: http://amzn.com/0596521065  Anyway, good luck.

Comment: I’ve posted a comment to that entry with lots of syntax missing from the file.

Comment: Is newer version available (for C# >= 5.0)?

Answer (score 3):

I've found this one useful:

http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html

Answer (score 1):

There is updated [AllInOne.cs](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/csharp/examples/AllInOne.cs) document in official ANTLR grammars repository (with C# 5 & 6 support). Also you can find [document with AllInOne](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Test/Utilities/Desktop/TestResource.resx) in Roslyn.